# How to break from the while loop? For Python string type

Tags: python, string, types

```
# Let's create a file and write it to disk.
filename = "test.dat"
# Let's create some data:
done = 0
namelist = []
while not done:
    name = raw_input("Enter a name:")
    if type(name) == type(""):
        namelist.append(name)
    else:
        break
```

For the Python code above, I tried, but could not break from the while loop. It always asks me to *"Enter a name:"*, whatever I input.
How to break from the loop?

Comment: Input you receive from a user will always be string input unless you convert it.

Comment: To debug this, you could have added some print statements, like `print name, repr(name), type(name)`, `print type("")`, `print type(name) == type("")` and so on, which would have shown the problem.  You can seldom go wrong by strewing print statement around.

Answer (score 4):

```
# Let's create a file and write it to disk.
filename = "test.dat"
# Let's create some data:
namelist = []
while True:
    name = raw_input("Enter a name:")
    if name:
        namelist.append(name)
    else:
        break
```

This breaks when entered nothing

Answer (score 1):

This is because `raw_input` always returns a string, i.e., `type(name) == type("")` is always true. Try:

```
while True:
    name = raw_input("Enter a name: ")
    if not name:
        break
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you both of youe! The code is fetched from other's webpage, so it is with bug!